# Как передать правильную ссылку в социальные сети из Fancybox+Joomla?

Tags: ajax, joomla, facebook-api, fancybox, vkontakte-api

Добрый день. На нашем сайте (joomla cms+t3framework) для вывода материала используется Fancybox. Постинг вк и другие социальные сети - Яндекс. Поделиться. или Плюсо.ру.
Как сделать так, чтобы пользователь перейдя из соцсетей по ссылке видел сайт, с активным модальным окном, а не только одну статью.

Answer (score 1):

В эту ссылку дописывать доп параметр, допустим `&modal=yes`, а на сервере сделать проверку на этот параметр, `if ($_GET["modal"] == "yes")`, и по результатам этой проверки выводить js функцию показа модального окна.